# ML vs MLPE (lmer in lme4)

Tags: r, linear-algebra, lme4, mixed-models

I am trying to conduct some landscape genetics analysis by testing association between landscape resistance matrices and pairwise genetic distances using linear mixed models.

When I run lmer package, I am unable to incorporate MLPE (Maximum likelihood population effects - regularly referenced and used when conducting this analysis). I am unable to find how to run MLPE approach in lmer anywhere too. As you can see via output, the model is fit by maximum likelihood.

Am I misunderstanding this, are they (MLPE and ML) the same thing as I appear to be able to run ML.

EDITED: including code and example of maximum likelihood being ran.

```
model_5 <- lmer(Genetic.Distance ~ (1 | Topography),
                            data = file, REML = FALSE)
summary(model_5)
```

OUTPUT

```
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['lmerMod']
Formula: Genetic.Distance ~ (1 | Topography)
   Data: file

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
-68399.5 -68377.3  34202.8 -68405.5    12087
```

Any advice, guidance or resources on how to conduct MLPE in lme4 would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you're conflating two different concepts: ML (maximum likelihood) usually refers to an *inference method* (as in "ML estimation") to obtain estimates for model parameters. MLPE and (more precisely) maximum likelihood population-effects (MLPE) *models* refer to random-effect models with a particular structure introduced by [Clarke et al.](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1198/108571102320.pdf) (see e.g. equation (4.1) and section 4 of their paper).

Comment: Not really an appropriate question for a coding site. You offer no data or code and the question sounds more directed at statistical concepts.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because There's a Bioinformatics forum in the StackExchange universe.

Comment: Hi all, many thanks for your input, I have added the code I am trying to run to assist in explaining my question. Any addition to the lmer formula or code for maximum likelihood population-effects (MLPE) would be helpful if possible.

Answer (score -1):

They are the same thing, both Maximum Likelihood.

Comment: Should be a comment.

Comment: This is wrong (and probably more of a comment than an answer). See my comment above.